# Cannot compile apache parquet from the source code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, googletest, parquet

This is the exact problem (source code from: https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp).
I'm using cmake:

```
parquet-cpp/test-build$ cmake ..
```

It says:

```
-- Found the Snappy library: /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/thirdparty/installed/lib/libsnappy.so
-- Found the ZLIB library: /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/thirdparty/installed/lib/libz.so
-- Found the GTest library: /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/thirdparty/googletest-release-1.7.0/libgtest.a
```

and then make VERBOSE=1: (it adds -ldl ../../../thirdparty/googletest-release-1.7.0/libgtest.a to the c++)

```
adam@gaia:~/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp -B/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f src/parquet/thrift/CMakeFiles/parquet_thrift.dir/build.make src/parquet/thrift/CMakeFiles/parquet_thrift.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/src/parquet/thrift /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet/thrift /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet/thrift/CMakeFiles/parquet_thrift.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f src/parquet/thrift/CMakeFiles/parquet_thrift.dir/build.make src/parquet/thrift/CMakeFiles/parquet_thrift.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `src/parquet/thrift/CMakeFiles/parquet_thrift.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles  40 41 42
[  5%] Built target parquet_thrift
make -f CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
[ 50%] Built target parquet_objlib
make -f CMakeFiles/parquet_shared.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/parquet_shared.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles/parquet_shared.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f CMakeFiles/parquet_shared.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/parquet_shared.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/parquet_shared.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles 
[ 50%] Built target parquet_shared
make -f CMakeFiles/parquet_static.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/parquet_static.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles/parquet_static.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f CMakeFiles/parquet_static.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/parquet_static.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/parquet_static.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles 
[ 50%] Built target parquet_static
make -f src/parquet/util/CMakeFiles/parquet_test_main.dir/build.make src/parquet/util/CMakeFiles/parquet_test_main.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/src/parquet/util /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet/util /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet/util/CMakeFiles/parquet_test_main.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f src/parquet/util/CMakeFiles/parquet_test_main.dir/build.make src/parquet/util/CMakeFiles/parquet_test_main.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `src/parquet/util/CMakeFiles/parquet_test_main.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/CMakeFiles  39
[ 51%] Built target parquet_test_main
make -f src/parquet/CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/build.make src/parquet/CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/src/parquet /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet/CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make -f src/parquet/CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/build.make src/parquet/CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
Linking CXX executable ../../debug/public-api-test
cd /home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/src/parquet && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -ggdb -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g    CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/public-api-test.cc.o  -o ../../debug/public-api-test -rdynamic ../../debug/libparquet_test_main.a ../../debug/libparquet.so -ldl ../../../thirdparty/googletest-release-1.7.0/libgtest.a -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build/debug 
CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/public-api-test.cc.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/src/parquet/public-api-test.cc:25: undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/src/parquet/public-api-test.cc:31: undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/src/parquet/public-api-test.cc:41: undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [debug/public-api-test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make[1]: *** [src/parquet/CMakeFiles/public-api-test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/adam/workspace/parquet-cpp/test-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Ask the authors of parquet-cpp

Comment: Can you show output of `make VERBOSE=1`? I'd like to see linker options `-L` and `-l`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I changed the output from pure "make" to "make VERBOSE=1".

Comment: When I build a test for cmake I usually add both libgtest.a and libgtest_main.a, for example:   ```target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_TEST_NAME}
        ${GTEST_LIBS_DIR}/libgtest.a
        ${GTEST_LIBS_DIR}/libgtest_main.a
        )```